# Select and update same table and row in one connection in mysql

Tags: mysql

This may seem like a repeat question, but it always seems to be questions involving more than one table. When a row in a table is selected, I will also need to +1 the view count in the same row. I know I can't use a trigger or two statements in the same query, but could both of these things be done with a single connection to the database? What would the preferred method be to both select a row and then +1 the view field?

Comment: `update table set val=val+1` - if you want the row too, you have to do two queries.

Comment: A stored procedure.  A `select` statement does not modify the database.

Comment: I think what he is trying to do here is to eliminate having to read the table twice, one on the update and another on the read. Please look at my answer below as it should you a way to update and read using 2 queries but you only operate on the table once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in the same connection, but I can't think of a way for that to be done using one query.

Here is how you would do that in a single transaction;

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE tbl SET view=view+1 WHERE id = 10;

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 10;
COMMIT;
```

A second "better" method you can do that which eliminates having to read the `tbl` table twice.

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET view = (@viewsCount := view + 1)
WHERE id = 10;
```

And to get the new value of the views count I would do something like this

```
SELECT @viewsCount;
```

A third way would be by utilizing the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function like so

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET view = LAST_INSERT_ID(view) + 1
WHERE id = 10;
```

Then to get the new view count you will need to execute this query immediately after the update. you can not execute any other queries after the update otherwise you will not get the intended value.

```
   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I think the first option  does what I want.  The second option with only one table read is really what I wanted to accomplish, but I need to do a select and and an update to to the view count. If it matters,  I don't need to get the updated view count with the select. I am just trying to find the most efficient way to track view counts on selected rows for use in a daily crone job.

Comment: You will have to break what you need to do into multiple steps. Use option #1 when you can. You could also add a trigger after select on the view column which will automaticly increment the value for you. I do not recommend the use of triggers and it cause things to slow down